How to use dynamically updated variable in Azure Pipeline each statement?
Here is a simple Azure Pipeline that illustrates my problem:-
jobs:
- job: BuildAndTest
  steps:
  - script: |
     echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=nuGetPackagesToBuild;isoutput=true]Configuration,Logging,UnitTests.Core"
    name: GetChangedProjects

- job: CreateChangedNuGetPackages
  dependsOn: BuildAndTest
  variables:
    nuGetPackagesToBuildFromBuildAndTestJob: $[ dependencies.BuildAndTest.outputs['GetChangedProjects.nuGetPackagesToBuild'] ]  
  steps:
    - ${{ each nuGetPackageToBuild in split(variables.nuGetPackagesToBuildFromBuildAndTestJob, ',') }} :
      - script: echo $(nuGetPackagesToBuildFromBuildAndTestJob)         # Configuration,Logging,UnitTests.Core
      - script: echo 'NuGet Packages to Build $(nuGetPackagesToBuild)'  # $(nuGetPackagesToBuild)
      - script: echo 'Creating NuGet Package1 ${{nuGetPackageToBuild}}' # $[ dependencies.BuildAndTest.outputs['GetChangedProjects.nuGetPackagesToBuild'] ]'
      - script: echo 'Creating NuGet Package2 $(nuGetPackageToBuild)'   # $(nuGetPackageToBuild)


I have a job (BuildAndTest) that creates an array (a string) of NuGet packages that need rebuilding. In the example above the list is hard coded but in my real script the list is dynamically generated from looking at the list of files in the Git commit.
The second job (CreateChangedNuGetPackages) reads the list of packages from the BuildAndTest job. It has an “each” statement which tries to iterate through the items in the array (a string converted into an array using split()).
You can see from the 4 echo statements that no matter what syntax I use the nuGetPackageToBuild variable never holds a useful value (e.g. “Configuration”). Instead, it holds the literal string “$[ dependencies.BuildAndTest.outputs['GetChangedProjects.nuGetPackagesToBuild'] ]”. It shouldn’t do because we can see from the first echo statement that the variable has correctly evaluated to “Configuration,Logging,UnitTests.Core”.
It appears as if the “each” statement has been evaluated at compile time and not at runtime so it is not possible to use “each” with a dynamically generated array.
If I hard code the list in the CreateChangedNuGetPackages job like this:-
nuGetPackagesToBuildFromBuildAndTestJob: 'Configuration,Logging,UnitTests.Core'

then the “each” statement appears to execute correctly and the nuGetPackagesToBuild variable contains the correct value and the loop is executed 3 times not once (because there are 3 elements in the array).
I was expecting that the "each" variable would be assigned its correct value at runtime.
How can I execute a pipeline step for each element in a dynamically generated array?

The each expression in YAML sample needs to read the Variable value at Compile time. But the Cross job variable: nuGetPackagesToBuild will expand at Runtime.
In this case, the Each expression cannot obtain cross-job variables when compiling. So it cannot successfully split the variable.
I am afraid that there is no out-of-box method can directly meet your requirement.
For a workaround, I suggest that you can split the Pipeline into two Pipelines(Job BuildAndTest -> Pipeline One and Job CreateChangedNuGetPackages -> Pipeline two). The first Pipeline will use PowerShell/Bash script to pass the variable value to the parameter value in the Second Pipeline.
Here is an example:
Pipeline One:
jobs:
- job: BuildAndTest
  steps:
    - task: PowerShell@2
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          $token = "$(pat)"      
          $url="https://dev.azure.com/{Orgname}/{Projectname}/_apis/pipelines/{PipelineRunID}/runs?api-version=5.1-preview"
          
          $token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))
          
          $JSON = "
          {
            
          
          
            `"resources`": {
              `"repositories`": {
                `"self`": {
                  `"ref`": `"refs/heads/main`"
                }
              }
            },
            `"templateParameters`": {
              `"nuGetPackagesToBuild`":`"Configuration,Logging,UnitTests.Core`"
            },
          
          
          
          }"
          
          
          $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Post -Body $JSON -ContentType application/json

Pipeline Two
parameters:
- name: nuGetPackagesToBuild
  type: string

jobs:
- job: CreateChangedNuGetPackages

  steps:
    - ${{ each nuGetPackageToBuild in split(parameters.nuGetPackagesToBuild, ',') }} :
      - script: echo 'Creating NuGet Package1 ${{nuGetPackageToBuild}}' 

Result:

Here is the doc about Runtime Parameter and Rest API: Runs - Run Pipeline

Thanks for the reply, Kevin. It is good to get the confirmation that my suspicion was correct. Your solution works. Now I need to decide whether I want to go for your more complex but flexible solution or whether I will use a hard coded, simpler solution that needs updating every time I add a new NuGet package.

(I am not able to vote that this answer is correct until I get 15 reputation but, for the record, it is correct).

@GSFatPracctice Glad to know that the answer can help you.
